# Getting all nodes with the same name using xpath for a BMECAT XML file?

Tags: php, xpath

This is my code:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('C:\myxml.xml');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace("bme", "http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/1.2/bmecat_new_catalog");

$expression = 'string(//bme:ARTICLE)';
var_dump($xpath->evaluate($expression));
```

This will var_dump the first of all the ARTICLE nodes. How can I get all of them?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: please show your result after `var_dump`.

Comment: A loop, yes, but what would I loop?

Comment: Show us your xml file and the var_dump

Comment: You should provide a link to the example XML file. Also you should update your question according to the additional information presented in your own duplicate [Reading a huge BME XML file using xpath in PHP? \[duplicate\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29249377/367456) (and remove it there).