# Getting all child nodes of a node using xpath expression?

Tags: php, xpath

This is the code that selects all ARTICLE nodes from my XML file:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('C:\myxml.xml');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace("bme", "http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/1.2/bmecat_new_catalog");

$list = $xpath->query('//bme:ARTICLE');
```

Now, how can I get ALL (direct and indirect) child nodes of that node? I tried that expression:

```
$list = $xpath->query('//bme:ARTICLE/*');
```

But that only gives me the direct children. In the end, I want to be able to compare each direct and indirect child node with a string.

Comment: Please just update your previous post instead of creating a new one for the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143406/getting-all-nodes-with-the-same-name-using-xpath-for-a-bmecat-xml-file

Comment: @PaulCrovella I'm afraid `descendant::*` will select only the descendant elements and not all nodes. `descendant::node()` would do that.